# Normally distributed rv

Tags: statistics

Here is a question from a past statistics test in my university:

> An automatic filling machine is to pour beer in $340 \ c.c.$ bottles . The amount poured $X$, is a normal variable having a mean of $331\  c.c.$ and a variance of $25$.
>
> Find $P(0.1 < (X-331)^2 < 0.4)?$

At first I tried this: I tried to change the expression which is in terms of $X^2$ to in terms of $X$. so I ended up with this:

$-\sqrt{10}/10 < X-331 < \sqrt{10}/5$

and solved for this and got $ 0.075$ as an answer.

Can anyone confirm my answer? Thank you

Comment: You think that the condition $0.1<(X−331)^2<0.4$ is equivalent to the condition that $−\sqrt{10}/10<X−331<\sqrt{10}/5$? Please reconsider.

Comment: $(X-331)^2/25\sim \chi_{1}^2$

Answer (score 0):

for $b>a>0$:

$$
\begin{aligned}
P(a<(X-\mu)^2<b)&=P(a/\sigma^2<Z^2<b/\sigma^2)\\
&=P\left(\sqrt{a/\sigma^2}<Z<\sqrt{b/\sigma^2}\right)+P\left(-\sqrt{b/\sigma^2}<Z<-\sqrt{a/\sigma^2}\right)\\
&=2\times \left[F\left(\sqrt{b/\sigma^2}\right)-F\left(\sqrt{a/\sigma^2}\right)\right]\\
\end{aligned}
$$

Where $F(x)$ is the Normal cumulative distribution function.

Which when $a=0.1$ and $b=0.4$ becomes:
$$
P(a<(X-\mu)^2<b)\approx 2 \times \left[F(0.1265)-F(0.0632)\right]\approx 0.0502
$$

The following does not prove anything but it does add some confidence that the above is OK-ish (or rather shares a common error with the above):

```
>> x=randn(1,10000)*5+331;
>> y=(x-331).^2;
>> sum( (y>0.1).*(y<0.4))/10000
ans =  0.050200
```

Answer (score 0):

$(X-331)^2/25$ is a Chi-square rv with one degree of freedom, as given in the comment to the question above. Thus,

$$
\mbox{chi2cdf}(0.4/25,1)-\mbox{chi2cdf}(0.1/25,1)=
0.0502.
$$

where $\mbox{chi2cdf}(x,n)$ denotes the cumulative distribution function of the chi-squared distribution at $x$ with $n$ degrees of freedom.

Comment: What does $chi2cdf(0.4/25,1)$ mean?

Comment: $\mbox{chi2cdf}(x,1)$ denotes the chi-square cumulative distribution function at $x$ with $1$ degree of freedom.

Comment: Well, I directly put the matlab code there, which I forgot to mention.